# I've this error :Error (10344): VHDL expression error at REG2.vhd(18): expression has 0 elements, but must have 4 elements

Tags: vhdl

I found this code which is a part of Exponentiation implementation, I believe this code is for parallel load register, the code had many mistakes, yet I tried to fix it and simplify it(simplification is to make it work), the original code is:

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity REG is --Register entity
Port ( CLK,set,reset,In_LOAD : in std_logic;
Din_p: in std_logic_vector(m-1 to 0);
Din_s: in std_logic;
Dout: out std_logic);
end REG;
architecture behavior of REG is
signal Q_temp: std_logic_vector(m-1 down to 0);
begin
Dout<=”0”;
comb:process(In_LOAD,Din_s)
begin
if(In_LOAD=”1”) then Q_temp<=Din_p;end if;
end process comb;
state: process(CLK,set,reset)
begin
if(reset=”1”) then Q_temp<=(others=>”0”);end if;
if(set=”1”) then Q_temp<= (others=>”1”);
elsif(CLK’event and CLK=”1”) then
Q_temp:=Din_p & Q_temp(m-1 down to 1);
end if;
Dout<= Q_temp(0);
end process state;
end behavior;
```

while the code I modified is:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity REG2 is --Register entity
generic (m: integer := 4);
Port ( CLK,In_LOAD : in std_logic;
Din_p: in std_logic_vector(m-1 to 0);
Dout: out std_logic);
end REG2;
architecture behavior of REG2 is
signal Q_temp: std_logic_vector(m-1 downto 0);
begin
Dout<='0';
process(In_LOAD, Din_p, CLK)
begin
if (CLK'event and CLK='1') then 
Q_temp <=Din_p;
elsif (In_LOAD='1') then
Q_temp <= Din_p & Q_temp(m-1 downto 1);
end if;
end process;
Dout <= Q_temp(0);
end behavior;
```

so my questions are : 1- why I'm getting this error :(Error (10344): VHDL expression error at REG2.vhd(18): expression has 0 elements, but must have 4 elements)?
2- this is a code for parallel load register, right?
thx

Comment: 1: With m=4, and `Din_p` as `std_logic_vector(m-1 to 0)` it results in range of `3 to 0`, which is a zero-length range.

Comment: You haven't indicated what line in your code corresponds to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of things are wrong with your code (and the original code).

- use the correct quote character `"` for bit strings and `'` for bits instead of `”`
- `downto` is one word, not `down to`
- `m` is not declared; perhaps this is supposed to be a generic?
- Assign to `Q_temp` using signal assignment `<=` instead of variable assignment `:=`
- Sensitivity lists for both your processes are incomplete
- As @Morten mentions: the direction of `Din_p` should probably `downto` instead of `to`

Bonus (pet peeve): don't use `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH` and `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED`, because they are not properly standardized. Use `ieee.numeric_std` instead.